# How to pass data from directive to parent component, but configured by grandfather component in Angular 9.0.6?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

## Initial situation:

There are four empty standard components `AComponent`, `BComponent` and `CComponent` created by Angular CLI as well as a `MenuComponent` with the selector `app-menu`.

The `MenuComponent` is embedded in the templates of `AComponent`, `BComponent` and `CComponent`, but each has different `appAttribute` values (123, 456, 789):

```
<app-menu [appAttribute]="123" (attributeChangedEvent)="myValue=$event"></app-menu>
```

The `AttributeDirective` applied to the `MenuComponent` takes the `appAttribute` defined in the templates of the `A-CComponents` and should make it available to the `MenuComponent` by means of an event. The `AttributeDirective` is working well and fires the custom event:

```
import {Directive, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appAttribute]'
})
export class AttributeDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input('appAttribute') appAttribute: string;
  @Output() attributeChangedEvent = new EventEmitter<boolean>();


  constructor() {
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.debug('attributeChangedEvent fired.'); 
    this.attributeChangedEvent.emit(true);
  }
}
```

## Problem to be solved:

How can I achieve that the event is received and evaluated by `MenuComponent` and that I do not have to embed `myValue` in every `A-CComponent` as shown above? `myValue` should be encapsulated within `MenuComponent` only, but configured outside.

**Short: How to pass data from directive to parent component, but configured by grandfather component in Angular 9.0.6?**

## Previous attempts at a solution:

- `@Output` and `EventEmitter` approach (see above)
- Using `@HostBinding` in the `AttributeDirective` (sending was successful, but host did not received any values, the targeted attributes went untouched)

Comment: Help me to understand your question: you just want to know when the `@Input` `appAttribute` changes?

Comment: @developer033 To reduce the problem to a minimum in a first step: Yes.
Based on this, I would like to process the value of `appAttribute` (123...) in `MenuComponent` later in the second step.

Comment: I may have got it wrong, but to check when the attribute changes, wouldn't you just use a setter `@Input('appAttribute') set(value: string) { ... };` or `ngOnChanges`?

Comment: @developer033 If I understand you correctly, then only the `AttributeDirective` knows that the value has been changed. But how do I get this information into the `MenuComponent`?

Comment: Through the `EventEmitter` you created, no? `@Input('appAttribute') set(value: string) { // ... this.attributeChangedEvent.emit(true); };`

Comment: @developer033 Yeah, I was hoping that's how it works, the way you describe it. However, I am having trouble receiving the emitted event. If I want to bind it, `myValue` or a corresponding function must always be placed in `A-CComponent`. But I need the binding of the directive event in the `MenuComponent`: `<app-menu [appAttribute]="123" (attributeChangedEvent)="myValue=$event"></app-menu>`. How can I bind the event to the `MenuComponent`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A [centralized event service](https://dev.to/jwp/the-angular-event-service-ech) is one method to establish cross component communication in any direction.

Or you may put in a static eventemitter into the directive or any component. Then any other component can subscribe or emit.